# What are the parameters of norm.cdf

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

For the function:

```
scipy.stats.norm.cdf(80,100,10)
```

Are the values `100` , `10` the mean and standard deviation respectively?

`80` is a continuous random variable.

Reading the documentation the meaning of these values is not described :

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the docs:
`cdf(x, loc=0, scale=1)` is the Cumulative density function.

and: The location (loc) keyword specifies the mean. The scale (scale) keyword specifies the standard deviation. So mean 100 and standard deviation 80.